# Android Running Task

Tags: android

How to get  the  list of applications which are  currently running in android system     and  how      to  update it on the layout with their icon   image.

And also help me to get all recent used application list and how to close one existing       running application.

```
 ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
 List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

 for (int i = 0; i < procInfos.size(); i++) {
     String st = procInfos.get(i).processName + " " + String.valueOf(procInfos.get(i).processName.length());
     //How to update it on layout in list format
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use custom listview.
create an array for app names and another for images(icons)
Then use custom listview to display it.
 [Here's a demo of custom listview](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92)